# A Program That Shuffles A Deck of Cards?

Tags: python

For my intro to programming class, I need to create a program that randomly shuffles a deck of cards and then outputs the rank & suit (shown as a unicode symbol) in a 4x13 grid. What I have so far is below. How do I get it to give a random output? It currently outputs the cards in order by rank and suit. How do I get it to output in a 4x13 grid? It currently outputs in a 13x4 grid.

Here's an example of what my output is *supposed* to look like:
[example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3Akm.png)

(For the class, my prof wanted us to list both the separate tuples & nested sequence which is why they're both there, sorry if it makes the code appear messy)

```
import random

#Cards
SUITS = "\u2663","\u2665","\u2666","\u2660"
PIPS = "A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"
deck = [("A","\u2663"),("2","\u2663"),("3","\u2663"),("4","\u2663"),
("5","\u2663"),("6","\u2663"),("7","\u2663"),("8","\u2663"),("9","\u2663"),
("10","\u2663"),("J","\u2663"),("Q","\u2663"),("K","\u2663"),("A","\u2665"),
("2","\u2665"),("3","\u2665"),("4","\u2665"),("5","\u2665"),("6","\u2665"),
("7","\u2665"),("8","\u2665"),("9","\u2665"),("10","\u2665"),("J","\u2665"),
("Q","\u2665"),("K","\u2665"),("A","\u2666"),("2","\u2666"),("3","\u2666"),
("4","\u2666"),("5","\u2666"),("6","\u2666"),("7","\u2666"),("8","\u2666"),
("9","\u2666"),("10","\u2666"),("J","\u2666"),("Q","\u2666"),("K","\u2666"),
("A","\u2660"),("2","\u2660"),("3","\u2660"),("4","\u2660"),("5","\u2660"),
("6","\u2660"),("7","\u2660"),("8","\u2660"),("9","\u2660"),("10","\u2660"),
("J","\u2660"),("Q","\u2660"),("K","\u2660")]

#Retrieve random card
def deal_card():
    for suit in SUITS:
        for pip in PIPS:
            print(suit + pip,end=" ")
        print()


#Main Portion
deal_card()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.
We are not a substitute for "I missed my class" -- that research is part of your responsibility before posting here, as is researching the many places that help you handle a desk of cards.

Comment: You could use [`random.shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle), unless the point of the assignment is to implement your own. In that case, look at the [Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: Would random.shuffle() replace deal.card()? If so, I can't, as the assignment requires me to have that function.

Comment: No, you'd call it on `deck` before you deal.

Comment: You print it by suit and number. Don't do that (mainly because it's useless); print a *deck* instead. You can choose how to arrange the number of rows and columns by changing the number of iterations in the major (row-wise) and minor (column-wise) print operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from itertools import product
from random import shuffle


SUITS = ["\u2663","\u2665","\u2666","\u2660"]
PIPS = ["A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"]
deck = list(product(PIPS, SUITS))
shuffle(deck)
```

Then put in your print logic.  Here is a fairly lazy print method that accomplishes what your example link shows:

```
for i in range(0, len(deck), 4):
    print("{} {} {} {}".format(deck[i][0]+deck[i][1],deck[i+1][0]+deck[i+1][1],deck[i+2][0]+deck[i+2][1],deck[i+3][0]+deck[i+3][1]))
```